# Truffle vs Hardhat vs Ethers vs Web3 what to choose for a beginner?

Tags: web3js, truffle, blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat

What is the most rewarding road map for a novice blockchain developer especially when having multiple technologies in the blockchain development realm ?

Answer (score 3):

There are use-cases for each one.
Il try give you some simplifications how to *understand* each one of them.

Truffle: Use it to **setup a project** that will interact with smart contracts and blockchain. It will also help you with Ganache(set your local blockchain).

Hardhat: Use it to **setup a project** that will interact with smart contracts and blockchain. It has very good documentation and is very begginer friendly.

Web3/Ethers: Are libraries that make your life easier on how to interact with blockchain and smart contracts. Both are very well documented and you should probably chose one of them! I would recommend you use Web3 for the start.
Also, getting deeper into Web3 library, you will see that sometimes you will need to use Ethers, just for a reason that there are things that are written better(example: Events Listening).

So to summarize:
Setup your projects with Truffle(if you want to use Ganache and do it locally) or hardhat(if you want to go on testnets or mainnet).

Interact with your contracts with Web3 library.

And one more thing:

Never learn "on a fly", have documentation near you: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/  and it will make your programming and debugging alot easier!

Answer (score 1):

Truffle, Hardhat, Brownie, Foundry (etc) are smart contract development frameworks. For making stuff you deploy to the blockchain.
Web3.js and Ethers.js are javascript libraries mainly used for interacting with smart contracts, via a wallet (metamask etc.) from the browser.

I haven't done it myself, but [speedrunethereum](https://speedrunethereum.com/) is a highly regarded resource (Austin Griffith). Alternatively, Patrick Collins has 24h long [courses on the freecodecamp.org](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ) youtube channel. These are what I would say are high quality resources for entry. Once you get some basic and solid understanding of "dapp" development go and participate in hackathons.

Answer (score 0):

with the new web3.js release of v4, web3 has better docs, better features than ethers, including a plugin that you can build, you can find more examples and tutorials about it, but before v4, ethers 4.x, 5.x and 6.x was better, also web3.js is backed by the Ethereum foundation (+ huge open source community) which is great and more reliable in the long term
https://web3js.org/